# Windows tr output file

Tags: windows, cmd, tr

I am attempting to run the following command:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "{\"" > output.txt
```

But it keeps erroring with:

```
tr: extra operand '>'
```

It seems like it's not interpreting the carrot properly.
The same thing also happens when I try this:

```
tr -f "{\"" < input.txt > output.txt
tr: extra operand '<'
```

Comment: You said "windows", are you using cygwin? The syntax you showed is correct (tested on ubuntu linux) so whatever the issue is it's with the shell

Comment: No just straight command prompt, using GNU32Tools

Comment: best to be specific. you are running `cmd.exe` ? That is basically DOS, and is probably confused by `"X\""` (the `\"` part). try removing just the `\"` . (yes, we'll have to fix removing `"` separately). Good luck.

Comment: `^` is the escape character in `cmd`, so try `cat file.txt | tr -d ^"{\"" > output.txt` or even `cat file.txt | tr -d ^^^"{\"" > output.txt` (the pipe may cause need of double-escaping)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `cmd` is getting confused with `"{\""`. First, the backslash works correctly in escaping the quote. But two consecutive quotes are taken by cmd to mean an escaped quote. Then the rest of the line is taken as the same sentence. You can see the effect using `printf`:

```
C:\>printf "%s\n" "x\"" > nul
x"
>
nul
```

Thus, `printf` takes each word individually, but `cmd` sees them as all part of a quoted string, and therefore does not parse the `> nul` as anything other than normal words.

The solution? Use two consecutive quotes in your string:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "{""" > output.txt
```

Comment: `cmd` does not escape `""` as one escaped `"`, the escape character in `cmd` is `^`, so `^"` escapes the `"`. There is at least one (external) command though that accepts `""`: [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl `cat file.txt | tr -d "{^"" > output.txt` doesn't work. `tr` sees the actual `^` character. On the other hand, with `""`, `tr` sees a single `"`.

Comment: The `^` is not handled as it appear in between `""` to `cmd`, so you need to escape the *first* quote, like `^"{""`, then it should work, I guess...

Comment: @aschipfl yes, `^"{""` works! But it seems `"{""` also works, and is 1 character shorter. In my answer, I had an extra `"` at the end, which in practice seems unnecessary.